# Angular remote containers - npm install in Dockerfile does not work

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, docker-container

Last week, I've added remote containers to my Angular project, following [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-tutorial). As the example shows, I started using the image of VS Code with Node and Typescript. The Dockerfile just installs @angular/cli and runs **npm install**. But it does not install any node_modules folder.

I've switched to a Node image with the configuration shown below, based on [this link](https://docs.docker.com/language/nodejs/build-images/). The Dockerfile is build without any problem.

As the logging shows CACHE, I also tried npm cache clean --force in the Dockerfile, but without any succes.

How can I get the node_modules installed when building the Dockerfile? Using the postCreateCommand in devcontainer.json, it starts the installation.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14
EXPOSE 4200

WORKDIR /myaccount

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
RUN npm i
COPY . .
```

**devcontainer.json**

```
{
    "name": "MyAccount",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "extensions": [
        "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
    ],
    "forwardPorts": [4200],
    //"postCreateCommand": "npm install"
}
```

**Log**

```
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:14                                                                                                                                                                  1.4s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:14@sha256:4164d987bfceb62b17db4938d535dd31fc50d6ee0b4e00ac7a774f82af408d48                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 69B                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /myaccount                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [3/6] COPY package*.json .                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [4/6] RUN npm install -g @angular/cli                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [5/6] RUN npm i                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [6/6] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => exporting to image
```

[image]

Comment: Can you see the other files in VSCode? How about if you open a terminal in the remote instance and navigate to `/myaccount`? Have you tried adding `"workspaceFolder": "/myaccount"` to your `devcontainer.json`?

Comment: Some details are missing. `npm i` runs as shown by your log output, so that's not your problem. Some possible explanation are: there is no `package.json` or it can't be found for some reason. Or it doesn't contain any dependencies. You need to provide more details. Just saying "I followed the instructions here" is not enough. Your question should be selfcontained and show all the information to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @cbr in my explorer of VS Code, I got all files listed in the Dev Container (same as local solution). When building the container and navigating to /myaccount, I see three files: Dockerfile, devcontainer.json & package-lock.json.

Comment: @super when I run the command manually the node_modules get installed. Package.json is there and containing dependencies. I've added an image of the workspace with the files in it.

Comment: Assuming you have `.devcontainer/Dockerfile`, try adding the following to your `devcontainer.json`: `"context": ".."` - this will change the Docker build context directory from `.devcontainer` to the parent directory, which is your workspace directory with your files.